# How To Protect Tomcat 7 Against Slowloris Attack

Tags: denial-of-service, tomcat7, attacks, malware

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7 to run my webapp on Linux. I scanned it by Acunetix and it's telling me that my webapp is vulnerable to "Slow HTTP Denial of Service Attack".
How can I protect it?

Acunetix is reffering me to [here](http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/08/protect-apache-slowloris-attack/), but it's about securing Apache, not Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat Security Team understands that this isn't a tomcat issue. [See here](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html#Not_a_vulnerability_in_Tomcat).

You can fix it by configuring a firewall (an example with iptables is discussed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42618/how-to-protect-tomcat-7-against-slowloris-attack)) or putting an Apache HTTP server in front off the tomcat server and configure it as described [here](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks).